# Illustrator can't color line

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I just started learning Illustrator, and I am trying to make a man but I can't color the middle line. It's always black, even though I changed it from the color's tools to blue.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### That's a stroked line, not a filled shape.

Your colors are backwards, so you will need to swap them. You can do this by using the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or by simply clicking on the swap colors option.

Then you can click back onto the black and remove it by selection the None option.

[image]

If you don't want a stroked path then use the rectangle tool <kbd>M</kbd> to create your shape.